# Get rid of second page that opens when executing an imacros script

Tags: javascript, html, css, imacros

How can I get rid of this second page that opens when using this href to execute an imacros script

[image: second Tab]

the first tab is a simple html page that contains this tag:

```
<a target="blank" 
  href="javascript:window.open('imacros://run/?m=#current.js');">
    <button>Run macro</button>
</a>
```

when clicking this link a second tab opens containing what in the image and **that the one I want to get rid of**. the third page contains what I want to execute.

note: I want to keep the first page open.

Comment: Try another web browser and test out?

Comment: I tried, but I also want it to work on cyberfox specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. If it works, it is better practice than using javascript hrefs and wrapping buttons in links

You can use a button instead of a link

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.querySelector("#imacro").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open(this.dataset.href)
  })
})
```

```css
.button {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button" id="imacro"
  data-href="imacros://run/?m=#current.js">
   Run macro
</a>
```

Comment: thanks this really works and better for practice, I changed the a tag to a button tag.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this but I would try:

```html
    <a
      href="#"
      onclick="javascript:window.open('imacros://run/?m=#current.js');return false;"
    >
      <button>Run macro</button>
    </a>
```

Comment: Maybe try the last version because I made an error in the first answer. If it still doesn't work it means that `imacros://run/?m=#current.js` doesn't work as URL because when replaced with e.g. `http://example.org/` it opens this page. Unfortunately I can't test the `imacros` URL.